# Check infrastructure for Python objects

Tags: python

#### Background

I am the author of a module that centres around a selection of similar classes, some of which inherit from others. The user instantiates a class and provides parameters to create a complicated object. These parameters must fulfil certain criteria to be valid; otherwise there will be errors further down the road. Checking some of these criteria takes a considerable amount of time or is otherwise unfeasible. Hence, some of the checks should only be run if the user desires it, usually after they encountered an error.

I have implemented an infrastructure that allows me to define individual checks as methods for the classes in question, register them as checks, and have a central function that runs all checks applying for a certain class.

#### Actual Code

```
# This provides an infrastructure for checks that works as follows:
# • Each check is registered as such by being decorated with `@Check`.
# • Each class that needs checks inherits from CheckEnvironment.
# • All checks are run with the method `run_checks`.

# This class exist just to mark functions by decoration
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self,function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self,*args):
        self.function(*args)

class CheckEnvironment(object):
    def run_checks(self, fail_fast=True):
        """
        Performs a series of checks that may not be feasible at runtime.

        Parameters
        ----------
        fail_fast : boolean
            whether to abort on the first failure.
            If false, an error is raised only
            after all problems are printed.
        """

        self.failed_check = False
        self.fail_checks_fast = fail_fast

        # execute all methods decorated with checker:
        visited = set()
        for cls in [self.__class__] + self.__class__.mro():
            for name,member in cls.__dict__.items():
                if name not in visited and isinstance(member,Check):
                    member(self)
                visited.add(name)

        if self.failed_check:
            raise ValueError("Check failed.")

    def _check_assert(self,condition,message):
        """
        Assert `condition` as part of a check. Raise `message` if it fails.
        """

        if not condition:
            self.failed_check = True
            if self.fail_checks_fast:
                raise ValueError(message)
            else:
                print(message)
```

#### Example of usage

```
from check import CheckEnvironment, Check

class House(CheckEnvironment):
    def __init__(self):
        self.doors = []
        self.windows = []

    def add_door(self,door):
        self.doors.append(door)

    def add_window(self,window):
        self.windows.append(window)

    @Check
    def check_doors(self):
        self._check_assert(
                self.doors,
                "Must have at least one door."
            )

    @Check
    def check_windows(self):
        self._check_assert(
                len(self.windows) > len(self.doors),
                "Must have more doors than windows."
            )

my_house = House()
my_house.run_checks() # fails
my_house.add_door("front door")
my_house.run_checks() # fails differently
my_house.add_window("kitchen window")
my_house.add_window("toilet window")
my_house.run_checks() # succeeds
```

#### Test

```
import unittest
from check import CheckEnvironment, Check

class SomeChecks(CheckEnvironment):
    def __init__(self,fail=True):
        self.invoked = []
        self.fail = fail

    @Check
    def A(self):
        self.invoked.append(1)

    @Check
    def B(self):
        self.invoked.append(2)
        self._check_assert( not self.fail, "Check A failed." )

    @Check
    def C(self):
        self.invoked.append(3)

    @Check
    def D(self):
        self.invoked.append(4)
        self._check_assert( not self.fail, "Check D failed." )

    def E(self):
        raise AssertionError("This method should not be run")

class DifferentChecks(SomeChecks):
    def A(self):
        raise AssertionError("This method should not be run")

    @Check
    def B(self):
        self.invoked.append(5)

    @Check
    def C(self):
        self.invoked.append(6)
        self._check_assert( not self.fail, "Check C failed." )

class TestChecks(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_default(self):
        X = SomeChecks(fail=True)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            X.run_checks()
        assert (2 in X.invoked) ^ (4 in X.invoked)

    def test_fail_slow(self):
        X = SomeChecks(fail=True)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            X.run_checks(fail_fast=False)
        self.assertListEqual( sorted(X.invoked), [1,2,3,4] )

    def test_success(self):
        X = SomeChecks(fail=False)
        X.run_checks()
        self.assertListEqual( sorted(X.invoked), [1,2,3,4] )

class TestInheritance(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_default(self):
        X = DifferentChecks(fail=True)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            X.run_checks()
        assert (4 in X.invoked) ^ (6 in X.invoked)
        assert all( i not in X.invoked for i in [1,2,3] )

    def test_fail_slow(self):
        X = DifferentChecks(fail=True)
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            X.run_checks(fail_fast=False)
        self.assertListEqual( sorted(X.invoked), [4,5,6] )

    def test_success(self):
        X = DifferentChecks(fail=False)
        X.run_checks()
        self.assertListEqual( sorted(X.invoked), [4,5,6] )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(buffer=True)
```

#### What feedback I seek

I am particularly interested in feedback on my way to mark checks (i.e., with a decorator modifying the class of the object) and options to make it more elegant. I am also interested in feedback on anything else except the use of whitespace.

Comment: This seems really abstract. Could you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: @Coal_: Please see my edit.

Comment: A problem I see with this approach is that the metadata of the original function is gone, so completion etc by the IDE might be compromised

Comment: @MaartenFabré: If that’s the case, wouldn’t that apply to all decorated functions?

Comment: Isn't that what [`functools.wraps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is for?

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks. That looks like a useful improvement.